# confusion to pass argument in asyncTask

Tags: android

In my application  i get image from server and those image build animation.this all things are gone be right way and i create method for it.this is the method::

```
  package com.animation;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class animation extends Activity {
    Button Buttona;
    AnimationDrawable animation;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.simple_anim);
        animation = new AnimationDrawable();

           try {
               for(int i=0;i<54;i++)
               {    
                xyz("girl000",i);
               }        
           animation.setOneShot(false);
           } catch (Exception e) {
            }
           img.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
           img.post(new Starter());

    }


    public void xyz(String str,int x)
    {
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
        "http://201.109.115.111/MRESC/images/test/girl/"+"girl000"+x+".png")
            .getContent());
            Drawable frame =new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
            animation.addFrame(frame, 50);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
    class Starter implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            animation.start();        
        }


    }
}
```

now **my problem** is it is take much time to load image from server so simply i plan to use asyncTask. but problem is i cant get judgment that how can i do this?
can you give me example(Note : i know asyncTask and use already but problem is passing argument as per my **`xyz()`** method declare)

Thanks
  nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

- Note that the loop now is in the background thread
- After each loop, you publish the progress to setup the animation frame
- At the very end, you run onPostExecute to run the remaining code

Note, that this is just a skeleton and rough sketches, you need to understand and debug it if there is any problem. I haven't run the code yet

```
    public class Animation extends Activity {
        Button Buttona;
        AnimationDrawable animation;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            animation = new AnimationDrawable();

            AsyncTask asyncTask = 
                new AsyncTask() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        // Execute this whole loop in background, so it doesn't 
                        // block your UI Thread
                        for(int i=0;i<54;i++) {    
                            xyz("girl000",i);
                        }        

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                public void xyz(String str,int x) {
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                                "http://201.109.115.111/MRESC/images/test/girl/"+"girl000"+x+".png")
                        .getContent());

                        // publish progress so that the bitmap is set on the UI Thread
                        publishProgress(bitmap);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // handle error
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... result) {
                    // handle the progress update to add the animation frame
                    Bitmap bitmap = result[0];
                    Drawable frame =new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                    animation.addFrame(frame, 50);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    if(result != null) {
                        // execute the rest of your instruction after the loop is over here
                        animation.setOneShot(false);
                        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.simple_anim);
                        img.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
                        img.post(new Starter());
                    } else {
                        // handle error
                    }
                }
            };

            asyncTask.execute();
        }

        class Starter implements Runnable {
            public void run() {
                animation.start();        
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am taking about http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
not name of class asynctask.

Comment: yes I understand that, you wrap the argument in xyz to a new Object wrapper and pass the Object Wrapper as param to the AsyncTask. Let me put the code to illustrate that. See the updated answer

Comment: i have update my entire code can you guide me with putting your code also

Comment: please help me on this topic.i really want to accept your answer but i need your help

Comment: Full code is attached. Note that I only illustrate the structure. All ideas are there in the bullet points. You need to understand it then debug if any error occurs (which is still possible).